# How can I extract absolute cell references from an externally linked cell range?

Tags: excel, reference, cell, extract, external

Is there an easy way (instead of manually copying and pasting) to extract only the absolute cell references from an externally linked cell range in excel?

I don't need the "sheet title" part of the external reference; just the absolute cell references as strings

Answer (score 0):

Yup...use Find & Replace to ditch the stuff you don't need. For instance, given formulas like `=[Book3]Sheet1!$D$10` simply use the Find & Replace functionality to replace the `=[Book3]Sheet1!` bit with a blank string.

Comment: Cool. Please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.